# Image background for a table that adjusts automatically to the 100% width keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, html-table, background-image

I am having problems with a table using a background image.

I need that the background image fills the 100% width of the div container and auto-complete the height keeping his aspect ratio.

```css
#pitch{background-color:d9ffd9;background:url('https://conceptdraw.com/a2048c3/p1/preview/640/pict--sport-field-plan-template-sport-field-plan---template.png--diagram-flowchart-example.png');background-position: top center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 100%,100%;}
```

```html
<div id="pitch-container">
<table id="pitch" width="100%">
<tr>
<td><img class="player-icon" src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/minicovers/sports-football-2-icon-12.png"><br>Player</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

something that...?

```
    <div class="pitch-container">
    <table id="pitch" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td><img class="player-icon" src="img/players/0.jpg"><br>Player</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
<style>
.pitch-container {
background-image: url(image.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, the only thing you have to do is set width of the image to 100%.
Keep your HTML same and your CSS should look something like :

```css
.player-icon
{
   width : 100%;
}
```

This mush solve your problem.

Comment: Please check this out

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the following codes. You should specify the height for the class depend on your background size.

```css
#pitch{background-color:d9ffd9;background:url('https://conceptdraw.com/a2048c3/p1/preview/640/pict--sport-field-plan-template-sport-field-plan---template.png--diagram-flowchart-example.png');background-position: top center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover !important;
    height: 600px;
    background-position:50% 50%;}
```

```html
<div id="pitch-container">
<table id="pitch" width="100%">
<tr>
<td><img class="player-icon" src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/minicovers/sports-football-2-icon-12.png"><br>Player</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not want to specify the height, it must be resize depending of the with pixels obtaining a responsive table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set image width to 100% inside the container and it will auto adjust height to maintain the aspect ratio.

```css
.player-icon
{
   width : 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pitch-container">
<table id="pitch" width="100%">
<tr>
<td><img class="player-icon" src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/minicovers/sports-football-2-icon-12.png"><br>Player</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```